# How to automatically get hyperlinks based on a condition?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

OS: Windows 10

Here's the basic idea:
[image]

I have a list of foods that are on the left side, and when I decide which foods I want, I then decide what order I want them in. After they are in the right order, G7-J7 (Linked Foods) should automatically place a hyperlink based on what food I selected in the **Order of Food**. How it pulls these links should be from the **List of Foods**. Then, at the bottom, there are 4 images that will automatically be shown based on what link is in the **Linked Food** boxes.

Basically, what I did, was I made the Linked Food 1 formula `=IF(G3 = "Ramen", D2, "No Link Found")`.

And then for the **Food 1** image, I did `=iferror(arrayformula(image(G7)),"")`

The image should automatically be there for whatever link I put in the G7 box now, but the G7 box is the main issue I'm having.

Everything works, but this is only an example. In my REAL project I'm doing, I have tons and tons of "foods" and I can't just put `=IF(G3 = "Ramen", "Lemonade", "Tofu", "Fruit Punch", ...and the hundreds of others`.

SO...What I'm wondering, is if there's an easier way to make these links automatically change, without having to manually put every single item from the **List of Foods** into the formula.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat unclear if the question is asking this for google docs or Excel, but the solution is basically the same either way.

What you want here is called "VLOOKUP". You will be replacing this line:

```
=IF(G3 = "Ramen", D2, "No Link Found")
```

with

```
=VLOOKUP(G3, C2:D8, 2, FALSE)
```

This will take the value of cell G3 (**Ramen** in the example case) and search the range of **C2:D8** (all the cells on the left of your table) until it finds it. Once it does it will go to the second column of the range (C = 1, D = 2) and take the matching cell value. The FALSE at the end has to do with sorting but shouldn't play a role here.

Note that your range needs to be the entire size of your foods list so change that D8 to D**X** where X is the size of your list in rows.

You can read the full syntax for VLOOKUP at: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en

Comment: This works! However, doing so made me realize another problem. The image sizes aren't all the same, so sometimes when I switch the URL, the image will be too small, too wide, or too tall. Is there to do this and also make the image automatically resize to fit the cell?